Ubuntu 20.04 startup slowdown
I'm new to Linux and I need help because I have observed that my Ubuntu 20.04 is slow to start. Below is the output of relevant commands:
$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 8.898s (firmware) + 7.958s (loader) + 2.747s (kernel) + 14.817s (userspace) = 34.422s 
graphical.target reached after 14.767s in userspace.

$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @14.767s
└─multi-user.target @14.767s
  └─plymouth-quit-wait.service @8.296s +6.468s
    └─systemd-user-sessions.service @8.280s +12ms
      └─network.target @8.262s
        └─NetworkManager.service @6.677s +1.584s
          └─dbus.service @6.574s +68ms
            └─basic.target @6.565s
              └─sockets.target @6.565s
                └─snapd.socket @6.564s +1ms
                  └─sysinit.target @6.557s
                    └─systemd-backlight@backlight:amdgpu_bl1.service @7.225s +525ms
                      └─system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice @1.268s
                        └─system.slice @396ms
                          └─-.slice @395ms

